Power Apps Plan error when trying to view SharePoint Online list item created in PowerAutomate
I have a SharePoint Online list where all items are created through a Flow in PowerAutomate. When a normal user wants to view the details of the item, he gets a "You need a Power Apps plan" error message. PowerApps are generally not made available to our normal users.

However me as an administrator (and with a PowerApps plan of course) can see all the details normally:

Things I have already tried:

Giving the user editing permission -> no change
Giving the user access to PowerApps -> user can see the details, but this solution is not preferred

Why is SharePoint Online behaving in this way? Is there a way to make the details available to the normal user without having to grant them access to PowerApps? Is this error maybe connected to this recent change in SharePoint Online (MC757614)?
Thanks in advance for any responses!

This is because the form has been customized with Power Apps.
You can revert back to the original SharePoint form.
On the list, as an admin, go to List settings > Form settings > Use the default SharePoint form



Thank you, this saved my problem. I didn't think so far that using PowerAutomate would change the settings of my list.
